# Como hago una regex para obtener de forma numérica estas coordenadas(x,y,z) apartir de una cadena de texto usando regex

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, regex, condiciones

Aquí dejo unos ejemplos de las cadenas que debería aceptar la regex, excepto el caso 5 que son números alfanuméricos y daría error en el resto del programa

```py
input_coords = "Some_text: 108,47,136" #caso valido 1
input_coords = "Some_textjadd: 108 , 47 , 136" #caso valido 2
input_coords = "Some_text: 108.5,47.9,136.6" #caso valido 3
input_coords = "Ssssome_text: 180,,136" #caso valido 4
input_coords = "Someddd_text: 180,47,13s6" #caso 5 NO valido
```

En los casos 1 , 2 y 3 las coordenadas la idea es que queden como floats, supongo que tendré que hacer un .group o un .groups() para ello pero me estoy complicando con la condición para evaluar los números

Quedarían algo así:

```py
float x = 108
float y = 47
float z = 136
```

o así

```py
float x = 108.5
float y = 47.9
float z = 136.6
```

Según el caso que la regex aceptase.

Y en el caso 4 la idea que se me ocurrió es hacer que la coordenada vacía tome el valor de 0, quizás definiendo esa coordenada previamente, el problema es que no se si la ausencia de un numero daría error.

Para el caso 5, debo no tomar los números porque mas adelante en el programa hare operaciones con las coordenadas y daría error.

Algo así se quedaría el código pero tengo complicaciones con la regex.

```py
input_coords = "Someddd_text: 180,47,13s6" #case 5 - FAIL case

while(True):
    if():
          REGEX IF CONDITION
    else:
          float x = none or previuos value
          float y = none or previuos value
          float z = none or previuos value
```

Comment: Cuando dices que el caso 5 da error, ¿es porque no habrá más texto después de las tres coordenadas?

Comment: Podrías agregar lo que has intentado hasta ahora por favor?

Comment: @ChemaCortes El caso 5 es porque en las coordenadas hay letras "infiltradas" entre los caracteres numericos, yo pense separarlos por las comas y con la funcion .group(0), .group(1) y .group(2) ir agarrando uno a uno los numeros, pero el tema es que agarre hasta las comas y que si una de las coordenadas no es posible pasarla a float, que no la modifique, suponiendo que inicialice las 3 coordenadas en 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La expresión regular que buscas es esta:

```
.*:\s*([0-9.]*?)\s*,\s*([0-9.]*?)\s*,\s*([0-9.]*?)$
```

Cada vez que aparecen paréntesis se abre un "grupo de captura", dedicado a capturar un número. El primero aparece tras una secuencia de caracteres arbitraria terminada en dos puntos y un espacio en blanco opcional (`\s*`), y termina cuando haya una coma (con espacios en blanco opcionales por delante y por detrás). El segundo grupo comienza tras esa primera coma y sigue hasta encontrar una segunda coma. El tercer grupo comienza tras la segunda coma y termina cuando termine la línea (`$`).

Dentro de cada grupo solo se admiten repeticiones de dígitos o el punto, por lo que si aparece una letra la expresión no encajará. Se admite tambíen cero repeticiones de estos elementos (por tanto un "valor vacío" para el número entre dos comas).

Veamos cómo funciona correctamente con tus input:

```
import re
def get_coords(input_coords):
  m = re.match(r".*:\s*([0-9.]*?)\s*,\s*([0-9.]*?)\s*,\s*([0-9.]*?)$", input_coords)
  if m:
    return m.groups()

for input_coords in ["Some_text: 108,47,136", "Some_textjadd: 108 , 47 , 136", "Some_text: 108.5,47.9,136.6", "Ssssome_text: 180,,136", "Someddd_text: 180,47,13s6"]:
  print(get_coords(input_coords))
```

Genera la siguiente salida:

```
('108', '47', '136')
('108', '47', '136')
('108.5', '47.9', '136.6')
('180', '', '136')
None
```

Vemos como captura correctamente los números, y como en el caso 4 el número central llega "vacío". En el último caso en cambio, al no encajar la expresión regular por haber letras dentro de uno de los números, la función retorna `None`.

Ahora bien, cómo tratar esos casos especiales en los que la regexp falla en algún número o en todos, no me ha quedado claro. Por el pseudocódigo que pones al final entendí que quieres "retener el valor de la iteración anterior", por así decir, y usarlo cuando falle la cadena siguiente.

Si esa interpretación es correcta, el siguiente código haría lo que pides:

```py
x, y , z = None, None, None
for input_coords in ["Some_text: 108,47,136", "Some_textjadd: 108 , 47 , 136", "Some_text: 108.5,47.9,136.6", "Ssssome_text: 180,,136", "Someddd_text: 180,47,13s6"]:
  r = get_coords(input_coords)
  if r:
    x = float(r[0]) if r[0] else x
    y = float(r[1]) if r[1] else y
    z = float(r[2]) if r[2] else z
  print(input_coords, "---->", (x,y,z))
```

Esto produce la siguiente salida:

```
Some_text: 108,47,136 ----> (108.0, 47.0, 136.0)
Some_textjadd: 108 , 47 , 136 ----> (108.0, 47.0, 136.0)
Some_text: 108.5,47.9,136.6 ----> (108.5, 47.9, 136.6)
Ssssome_text: 180,,136 ----> (180.0, 47.9, 136.0)
Someddd_text: 180,47,13s6 ----> (180.0, 47.9, 136.0)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias me funciono perfecto, además la explicación me ayuda un montón

Answer (score 1):

Ya que alguien dio una respuesta, daré mi versión.

No es necesario usar expresiones regulares para lograr lo que buscas. Puedes hacerlo con los recursos que ofrece Python. Así que presento una alternativa sin usar regex.

A continuación, coloco un código que hace lo que buscas:

```
casos = ("Some_text: 108,47,136",
         "Some_textjadd: 108 , 47 , 136",
         "Some_text: 108.5,47.9,136.6",
         "Ssssome_text: 180,,136",
         "Someddd_text: 180,47,13s6")

for caso in casos:
    coords = caso.split(":", 1)[1].strip()

    x, y, z = (coord.strip() for coord in coords.split(","))

    try:
        x = 0 if(x == "") else float(x)
        y = 0 if(y == "") else float(y)
        z = 0 if(z == "") else float(z)
    except ValueError:
        print("Hubo un error al convertir una de las coordenadas a flotante: ", caso)
        continue

    print(x, y, z)
```

Produce:

```
108.0 47.0 136.0
108.0 47.0 136.0
108.5 47.9 136.6
180.0 0 136.0
Hubo un error al convertir una de las coordenadas a flotante:  Someddd_text: 180,47,13s6
```

---

A continuación, me dedicaré a explicar que hace cada seccion:

```
coords = caso.split(":", 1)[1].strip()
```

`caso.split(":", 1)` separa la cadena en dos partes: lo que está antes del ":" y lo que está después. Tomamos el segundo item de la lista, que será lo que está despues del ":".
A la cadena obtenida, le quitamos los espacios que tiene alrededor.

```
x, y, z = (coord.strip() for coord in coords.split(","))
```

`coords.split(",")` separa la cadena según la prescencia de la ,. Por ejemplo para el caso 1 devolvera `['108','47','136']`. Posteriormente recorremos cada coordenada con una expresion generadora y le quitamos a cada coordenada los espacios que la rodean. Por ultimo desempaquetamos el generador (lo que devuelve primero el generador en x, lo segundo en y y lo tercero en z).

```
try:
    x = 0 if(x == "") else float(x)
    y = 0 if(y == "") else float(y)
    z = 0 if(z == "") else float(z)
except ValueError:
    print("Hubo un error al convertir una de las coordenadas a flotante: ", caso)
    continue
```

Probamos con que si cada coordenada es igual a una cadena vacía, devolver 0. Y si no convertir la coordenada en flotante. Si esto no tiene exito en alguna coordenada, se imprime un mensaje en pantalla indicando el fallo y con que caso falló. Luego procesa el siguiente caso.

Si no hubo ningún error, devuelve en pantalla el resultado.

---

Nota: el código lo hice asumiendo que el formato de la cadena siempre va a ser un texto, seguido de : y 3 textos separadas por ,. Si esto no se cumple, puede ocurrir un error.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la solución sin usar las regex

Comment: De nada c: Te aviso que hice una edicion para poner una aclaración. Está abajo de todo.

Answer (score 0):

La función `extraer` recibe una cadena y extrae de ella los valores en punto flotante al final de la línea. Los valores son retornados en una lista. Si alguno de estos no ear un valor válido, retorna `None`.

```
def extraer(cadena):
    try:
        pos = cadena.rfind(": ")
        values = [float((x or '0').strip()) for x in test[pos+1:].split(",")]
    except ValueError:
        values = None
    return values
```

*Funcionamiento*

Primero ubicamos el último ": " en la cadena. Lo que está a la derecha de esa posición lo dividimos por las ",", eliminamos los blancos y convertimos a `float`.

La expresión `x or '0'` nos asegura de que el campo extraído siempre tenga al menos un digito. Si `x` es la cadena vacía, entonces es `False`, por lo que Python evalua el resto de la expresión. El caracter `'0'` es `True` y el resultado de esta expresión lógica es el último valor **evaluado**; en este caso, `'0'`, que es justo lo que necesitamos.

De otro modo, al intentar procesar un valor faltante (como en `"180,,136"`), nos daría `ValueError`.

Si después de esto el campo no es válido como `float`, se producirá una excepción `ValueError`, en cuyo caso toca retornar `None`.

#### Demo

```
def extraer(cadena):
    try:
        pos = cadena.rfind(": ")
        values = [float((x or '0').strip()) for x in test[pos+1:].split(",")]
    except ValueError:
        values = None
    return values

tests = [
    "Some_text: 108,47,136",
    "Some_textjadd: 108 , 47 , 136",
    "Some_text: 108.5,47.9,136.6",
    "Ssssome_text: 180,,136",
    "Someddd_text: 180,47,13s6"]

for test in tests:
    r = extraer(test)
    if r:
        print(test, r)
    else:
        print(test, "No valido")
```

produce:

```
Some_text: 108,47,136 [108.0, 47.0, 136.0]
Some_textjadd: 108 , 47 , 136 [108.0, 47.0, 136.0]
Some_text: 108.5,47.9,136.6 [108.5, 47.9, 136.6]
Ssssome_text: 180,,136 [180.0, 0.0, 136.0]
Someddd_text: 180,47,13s6 No valido
```